# Using SQL inside vba to display in cells

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access-2010

Trying to run this code for it to display the DemandNumber * PartNumber. Keep getting "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error.

When going to the debugger it is highlighting this line:

```vb
 Sheets("ProjectedUnits").Cells(2 + i, 1).Value = DemandNumber(i)(0)
```

FUll code

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub CalculateBT_Click()

Dim dbConnection As Object
Dim strSQL As String
Dim strConnection As String 'text data
Dim rs As Object


Set dbConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
strConnection = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & "Data Source=" & Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\MyMRPDatabase2.accdb"

' Get the value from the GUI textbox and split it into an array of values
Dim WeekValues As Variant
WeekValues = Split(WeekNumberTB.Value, ", ")

strSQL = "SELECT WeekNumber, ProjectedUnits FROM MarketDemand " & _
         "WHERE (WeekNumber IN (" & Join(WeekValues, ", ") & ")) " & _
         "ORDER BY WeekNumber ASC;"
        
dbConnection.Open (strConnection)
Set rs = dbConnection.Execute(strSQL)

Dim DemandNumber As Object 'use Object instead of Collection
Set DemandNumber = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

Dim ProjectedNumber As String
Dim WNumber As Collection 'remove the "New" keyword
Set WNumber = New Collection 'initialize WNumber with the New keyword later in the code

Do While (Not rs.EOF)
    WNumber.Add rs.Fields(0)
    ProjectedNumber = rs.Fields(1)
    DemandNumber.Add Array(WNumber, ProjectedNumber)
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
        
rs.Close
dbConnection.Close

If DemandNumber.Count = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No data found in DemandNumber array."
    Exit Sub
End If

Worksheets("ProjectedUnits").Activate
Sheets("ProjectedUnits").Range("B2:S" & Sheets("ProjectedUnits").Cells(Sheets("ProjectedUnits").Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).ClearContents

Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To DemandNumber.Count - 1

Sheets("ProjectedUnits").Cells(1, 1).Value = "Week Number"
Sheets("ProjectedUnits").Cells(2 + i, 1).Value = DemandNumber(i)(0)
Sheets("ProjectedUnits").Cells(1, 2).Value = "PartID"
Sheets("ProjectedUnits").Cells(1, 3).Value = "Part01"
Sheets("ProjectedUnits").Cells(2 + i, 3).Value = DemandNumber(i)(1) * 1
Sheets("ProjectedUnits").Cells(1, 4).Value = "Part02"
Sheets("ProjectedUnits").Cells(2 + i, 4).Value = DemandNumber(i)(1) * 1
Sheets("ProjectedUnits").Cells(1, 5).Value = "Part03"
Sheets("ProjectedUnits").Cells(2 + i, 5).Value = DemandNumber(i)(1) * 1
Sheets("ProjectedUnits").Cells(1, 6).Value = "Part04"
Sheets("ProjectedUnits").Cells(2 + i, 6).Value = DemandNumber(i)(1) * 1
Sheets("ProjectedUnits").Cells(1, 7).Value = "Part05"
Sheets("ProjectedUnits").Cells(2 + i, 7).Value = DemandNumber(i)(1) * 2
Sheets("ProjectedUnits").Cells(1, 8).Value = "Part06"
Sheets("ProjectedUnits").Cells(2 + i, 8).Value = DemandNumber(i)(1) * 2
Sheets("ProjectedUnits").Cells(1, 9).Value = "Part07"
Sheets("ProjectedUnits").Cells(2 + i, 9).Value = DemandNumber(i)(1) * 2
Sheets("ProjectedUnits").Cells(1, 10).Value = "Part08"
Sheets("ProjectedUnits").Cells(2 + i, 10).Value = DemandNumber(i)(1) * 4
Sheets("ProjectedUnits").Cells(1, 11).Value = "Part09"
Sheets("ProjectedUnits").Cells(2 + i, 11).Value = DemandNumber(i)(1) * 2
Sheets("ProjectedUnits").Cells(1, 12).Value = "Part10"
Sheets("ProjectedUnits").Cells(2 + i, 12).Value = DemandNumber(i)(1) * 2
Sheets("ProjectedUnits").Cells(1, 13).Value = "Part11"
Sheets("ProjectedUnits").Cells(2 + i, 13).Value = DemandNumber(i)(1) * 2
Sheets("ProjectedUnits").Cells(1, 14).Value = "Part12"
Sheets("ProjectedUnits").Cells(2 + i, 14).Value = DemandNumber(i)(1) * 2
Sheets("ProjectedUnits").Cells(1, 15).Value = "Part13"
Sheets("ProjectedUnits").Cells(2 + i, 15).Value = DemandNumber(i)(1) * 2
Sheets("ProjectedUnits").Cells(1, 16).Value = "Part14"
Sheets("ProjectedUnits").Cells(2 + i, 16).Value = DemandNumber(i)(1) * 1
Sheets("ProjectedUnits").Cells(1, 17).Value = "Part15"
Sheets("ProjectedUnits").Cells(2 + i, 17).Value = DemandNumber(i)(1) * 1
Sheets("ProjectedUnits").Cells(1, 18).Value = "Part16"
Sheets("ProjectedUnits").Cells(2 + i, 18).Value = DemandNumber(i)(1) * 1
Sheets("ProjectedUnits").Cells(1, 19).Value = "Part17"
Sheets("ProjectedUnits").Cells(2 + i, 19).Value = DemandNumber(i)(1) * 2

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: A quick search in the Internet gave me https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/error-1004-application-defined-object-defined/ . This site gives me a short explaination "The error can also occur when you have incorrectly referenced an object in your code"

Comment: Because there are no line number has mentiononed, you have to go trough line by line to find the source.

Comment: While the debugger is paused, what is the value of `DemandNumber(i)(0)`? If that errors, what is the value of `DemandNumber(i)` ? And the value of `i`? Is there a reason you have to use an `ArrayList`?

Comment: In the line `DemandNumber.Add Array(WNumber, ProjectedNumber)` why is `WNumber` a collection and not just a string eg `WNumber = rs.Fields(0)` ?

Comment: Solved issue! @CDP1802 you were correct with WNumber being dimmed as String and not a collection.

Answer (score 1):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CalculateBT_Click()

    Dim dbConnection As Object, rs As Object
    Dim strConnection As String, strSQL As String 'text data
    
    Set dbConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    strConnection = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                    "Data Source=" & Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\MyMRPDatabase2.accdb"
    
    ' Get the value from the GUI textbox and split it into an array of values
    Dim WeekValues As Variant
    WeekValues = Split(WeekNumberTB.Value, ", ")
    
    strSQL = "SELECT WeekNumber, ProjectedUnits FROM MarketDemand " & _
             "WHERE (WeekNumber IN (" & Join(WeekValues, ", ") & ")) " & _
             "ORDER BY WeekNumber ASC;"
            
    dbConnection.Open (strConnection)
    Set rs = dbConnection.Execute(strSQL)
    
    Dim DemandNumber As Object 'use Object instead of Collection
    Set DemandNumber = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    
    Dim ProjectedNumber As String
    Dim WNumber As String
    
    Do While (Not rs.EOF)
        WNumber = rs.Fields(0)
        ProjectedNumber = rs.Fields(1)
        DemandNumber.Add Array(WNumber, ProjectedNumber)
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
            
    rs.Close
    dbConnection.Close
    
    If DemandNumber.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No data found in DemandNumber array."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim i As Long, lastrow As Long, ar As Variant
    With Sheets("ProjectedUnits")
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("B2:S" & lastrow).ClearContents
        
        ' header
        .Cells(1, 1) = "Week Number"
        .Cells(1, 2) = "PartID"
        For i = 3 To 19
            .Cells(1, i) = Format(i - 2, "Part00")
        Next
    
        ' records
        For i = 2 To DemandNumber.Count + 1
            ar = DemandNumber(i - 2)
            .Cells(i, 1) = ar(0)
            .Cells(i, 3) = ar(1) * 1
            .Cells(i, 4) = ar(1) * 1
            .Cells(i, 5) = ar(1) * 1
            .Cells(i, 6) = ar(1) * 1
            .Cells(i, 7) = ar(1) * 2
            .Cells(i, 8) = ar(1) * 2
            .Cells(i, 9) = ar(1) * 2
            .Cells(i, 10) = ar(1) * 4
            .Cells(i, 11) = ar(1) * 2
            .Cells(i, 12) = ar(1) * 2
            .Cells(i, 13) = ar(1) * 2
            .Cells(i, 14) = ar(1) * 2
            .Cells(i, 15) = ar(1) * 2
            .Cells(i, 16) = ar(1) * 1
            .Cells(i, 17) = ar(1) * 1
            .Cells(i, 18) = ar(1) * 1
            .Cells(i, 19) = ar(1) * 2
        Next i
    End With
    MsgBox i - 2 & " records", vbInformation
End Sub
```